# Aggregate and filter from one index to another through a third

Tags: elasticsearch, search, faceted-search, elasticsearch-aggregation

On my Elasticsearch server I have three indices: `Person`, `Archive` and `Document`.

- Each document has a `archive` field which is the `_id` of the `Archive` it is in.
- Each archive has a `owner` which is the `_id` of the `Person` that is the owner of the archive.

With the indices above I can aggregate documents into buckets of archives and archives into buckets of owners.

How can I also include the documents in the person aggregations so if I filter on a specific person I get the archives and their documents that belongs to the person instead of only the archives?

---

This is what I have so far to filter and aggregate the archives into buckets of owners:

```
{
  "post_filter": {
    "terms": {
      "owner": [
        "my_owner_id"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "_filter_archive": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "owner": [
            "my_owner_id"
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "archive": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "archive"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have modeled your Elasticsearch indices  from the relational databases thinking and approach, which is most of the times wrong. With the current configuration, you cannot achieve what you want.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Do you have a recommendation for a functional Elasticsearch model?

Comment: If possible, denormalize your data and have everything in a single index. What ES version are you using?

Comment: I'm using ES 6.1

Comment: How many documents an archive can have and how many archives a person can have?

Comment: There are no limits on any of them

Comment: I meant realistically, not theoretically.

Comment: I would guess hundreds of archives and hundreds of thousands of documents

Comment: How often a Person will be updated? The same question for Archive?

Comment: I would guess weekly for both

Comment: It would be good if you could think about these requirements a bit better. This sort of things matter in a scenario like this. What operations are possible for an archive (add another document, remove a document etc)? And here I refer to a realistic/practical scenario, so would be good if the product owner/manager would have this information.

Comment: This type of aggregation that you need - is it something you'd use frequently or very rarely? Do you need those relationships for other queries/aggregations? If not maybe you could create two queries or multiple queries to achieve what you need and don't have to rely on ES relationships.

Comment: Only one query and pretty often

Comment: Will this query results be displayed in a web page or similar? What is the point of showing one Person with an Archive and 10000 Documents? Is this even useable? Can you show list of Persons with each own person's Archive and then, clicking on an Archive the list of documents expands?

Comment: The query will only display the documents but I want the facet filter for persons to filter the documents and not only the archives

Comment: This will be difficult to answer because it seems you are missing some details. The easy answer is: use `nested` documents or parent-child relationship. Which one to use in your case depends on a lot of factors. My suggestion is to try them both and test. See how well they perform. The third option is to denormalize your data completely. That's the reason I asked about updates, how frequent they are, how large a Person document is, how large an Archive document is etc. If you are not prepared to answer these questions, then test `nested` and parent-child and choose one or the other. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be difficult to answer because it seems you are missing some details. The easy answer is: use nested documents or parent-child relationship. Which one to use in your case depends on a lot of factors. My suggestion is to try them both and test. See how well they perform. The third option is to denormalize your data completely. That's the reason I asked about updates, how frequent they are, how large a Person document is, how large an Archive document is etc. If you are not prepared to answer these questions, then test nested and parent-child and choose one or the other. Good luck!